# map 100% reduce 100%, Task Failed

Tags: python, hadoop, hadoop2, hadoop-streaming

I'm new to Hadoop and I'm running a Map Reduce process to count revenue of different stores. 
The mapper and reducer programs work perfectly. And i double-checked the files and the direcotries.

When i run the MapReduce command which is:

```
hadoop jar /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce1/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-2.5.0-mr1-cdh5.3.2.jar \
  -mapper mapper.py \
  -reducer reducer.py \
  -input /home/anwarvic \
  -output /joboutput
```

it gives the following output:

```
17/04/30 05:48:13 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/04/30 05:48:14 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.tracker is` deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.address
packageJobJar: [mapper.py, reducer.py] [] /tmp/streamjob7598928362555913238.jar tmpDir=null
17/04/30 05:48:15 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032 
17/04/30 05:48:16 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
17/04/30 05:48:21 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 5
17/04/30 05:48:21 INFO net.NetworkTopology: Adding a new node: /default-rack/127.0.0.1:50010
17/04/30 05:48:24 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:6
17/04/30 05:48:25 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1493523215757_0002
17/04/30 05:48:27 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1493523215757_0002
17/04/30 05:48:28 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://anwar-computer:8088/proxy/application_1493523215757_0002/
17/04/30 05:48:28 INFO streaming.StreamJob: getLocalDirs(): [/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local]
17/04/30 05:48:28 INFO streaming.StreamJob: Running job: job_1493523215757_0002
17/04/30 05:48:28 INFO streaming.StreamJob: Job running in-process (local Hadoop)
17/04/30 05:48:29 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 0%  reduce 0%
17/04/30 05:49:08 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 17%  reduce 0%
17/04/30 05:49:10 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 0%  reduce 0%
17/04/30 05:49:41 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 17%  reduce 0%
17/04/30 05:49:42 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 0%  reduce 0%
17/04/30 05:49:43 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 17%  reduce 0%
17/04/30 05:49:45 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 0%  reduce 0%
17/04/30 05:50:07 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 17%  reduce 0%
17/04/30 05:50:08 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 0%  reduce 0%
17/04/30 05:50:37 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 100%  reduce 100%
17/04/30 05:50:41 INFO streaming.StreamJob: Job running in-process     (local Hadoop)
17/04/30 05:50:41 ERROR streaming.StreamJob: Job not successful.     Error: Task failed task_1493523215757_0002_m_000000
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0

17/04/30 05:50:41 INFO streaming.StreamJob: killJob...
17/04/30 05:50:41 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Killed application application_1493523215757_0002
Streaming Command Failed!
```

The output basically says that the Job is not successful although the Map and Reduce processes are done by 100%

As states in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302262/hadoop-streaming-command-failure-with-python-error) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302262/hadoop-streaming-command-failure-with-python-error), I added the shebang headers to both **mapper.py** and **reduce.py** files:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

By the way, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460522/hadoop-streaming-job-failed-error-in-python) didn't work for me!

I've been in this problem for around 20 hours.. so any help would be so appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend following steps:

1. Visit your job tracker URL: `http://anwar-computer:8088/proxy/application_1493523215757_0002/`
2. Go to failed mappers (Your log says that mapper has failed `Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0`). You can see the Exception trace.
3. For more detailed logs, following the `logs` link available within the failed mappers page.

Analyze the logs and most likely you can get to the root cause.

Possible root causes:

1. Your data might be malformed or different than what you are expecting in the `Mapper`.
2. Another reason could be the data size and available memory on the node. Data might be compressed and during mapper step when it is uncompressed, it is overflowing the memory.

I am suspecting that point 1 could be the reason as the process has tried to run the mapper for multiple time and failing.

```
17/04/30 05:48:29 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 0%  reduce 0%
17/04/30 05:49:08 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 17%  reduce 0%
17/04/30 05:49:10 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 0%  reduce 0%
17/04/30 05:49:41 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 17%  reduce 0%
17/04/30 05:49:42 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 0%  reduce 0%
17/04/30 05:49:43 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 17%  reduce 0%
17/04/30 05:49:45 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 0%  reduce 0%
17/04/30 05:50:07 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 17%  reduce 0%
17/04/30 05:50:08 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 0%  reduce 0%
```

Further more, you can add more logs in your `Mapper` to get better details.

Alternatively, you can also enable logger (add `--loglevel DEBUG` parameter to hadoop command). e.g.

```
hadoop \
  --loglevel DEBUG \
  jar /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce1/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-2.5.0-mr1-cdh5.3.2.jar \
  -mapper mapper.py \
  -reducer reducer.py \
  -input /home/anwarvic \
  -output /joboutput
```

Reference: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/CommandsManual.html